# Как правильно вызвать php скрип из jQuery?

Tags: jquery, php

Есть файл `some.php`:

```
<?php    
     echo "something text";
?>
```

Также есть файл `some.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("#some").load("http://shv.ru/www/wp-content/themes/daily-digest-         30/some.php");

});
```

В шаблоне есть тег `<div id="some"></some>`, в который должен выводиться результат моего php скрипта,но этого не происходит. В веб консоли Мозиллы ошибок не выводится, в чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("some.php", function(data){
        $("#some").html(data);
    });
});
```

Какая у вас ошибка я не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("file.php", {сюда данные}, function(data){cюда приходим с ответом});
```

Да, а если хотите именно вызвать функцию в файле, передайте ее имя в POST-переменной и соответственно разрулите в file.php

Comment: не работает ни get, ни post, ни load. Может это у вордпресса какие нить особенности????

Comment: А Вы подключили Jquery? <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>